# How to define width in error bars in ggplot2 (R)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, confidence-interval

I have the following data that I'm trying to plot. I'm trying to change the width of the error bar but I run into an error that says `Width not defined. Set with position_dodge(width = ?)`. I tried doing the position_dodge..but it didn't help. Any suggestions?

```
library(ggplot2)

time <- c("t1","t1","t1","t1","t1","t1","t2","t2","t2","t2","t2","t2")
species <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2)
value <- c(1,2,3,11,12,13,4,5,6,11,12,13)

df <- data.frame(time, species,value)
df$time <- as.factor(df$time)
df$species <- as.factor(df$species)

ggplot(df,aes(x=time, y=value, color = species, group = species)) + # Change fill to color
  theme_bw() + 
  geom_point() + 
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, position = "dodge") + 
  stat_summary(
    geom="errorbar", 
    fun.data= mean_cl_boot, 
    width = 0.1, size = 0.2, col = "grey57") + 
  # Lines by species using grouping
  stat_summary(aes(group = species), geom = "line", fun.y = mean) +
  ylab("Fitness")
```

Comment: What do you use this `position = "dodge"` for?

Comment: I think its for plotting the mean

Comment: I don't think you need it if your datapoints are not overlapping. Otherwise you should probably keep it constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position dodge is used to show all data points when data points overlap, I am not sure if this is of any use in your example and you may find that just removing this argument solves the issue if your data are not overlapping. Keeping it constant alternatively solves the issue:

```
pd<-position_dodge(0.5)
  ggplot(df,aes(x=time, y=value, color = species, group = species)) + # Change fill to color
  theme_bw() + 
  geom_point(position = pd) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, position = pd) + 
  stat_summary(
    geom="errorbar", 
    fun.data= mean_cl_boot, 
    width = 0.1, size = 0.2, col = "grey57",
    position = pd) + 
  # Lines by species using grouping
  stat_summary(aes(group = species), geom = "line", fun.y = mean, position = pd) +
  ylab("Fitness")
```

Just edited to keep everything from breaking apart.